# How can I send out my caller ID info?

Tags: iphone, ios, caller-id, phone.app

Is there a way to send out my Caller ID info to people not on my contact list, or to people whose contact list I am not on?

Answer (score 2):

If your carrier supports showing Caller ID, it can be configured under Settings → Phone → Show My Caller ID. For more options, contact your carrier.